# Why does the SQL query throws a termination error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table which has some data. I have another table which takes those data and saves it to a new table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE database.dbo.[table2]

INSERT INTO [database].[dbo].[table2]
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 101) AS [Date], -- ADD YESTERDAY'S DATE
    SUM([EMR ORDERS]) AS LastWeekEMROrders,
    SUM([ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS]) AS LastWeekAccLabOrders,
    SUM([LAB_RESULT]) AS LastWeekLabResults,
    ((SELECT [EMR ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable]) - (SELECT [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable])) AS [LastWeekPendingProcessing]
FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable]
WHERE
    [Date] >= DATEADD(day, -((DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) - 6,
              DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) --PREVIOUS SUNDAY
    AND
    [Date] <= DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7,
              DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) --PREVIOUS SATURDAY
```

This is the error I get:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Basically the query it supposed to take the data from the original table and calculate based on week. It was working fine but I am not sure why happened...

Please help me resolve the issue.

Original table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this is most likely your problem: `((SELECT [EMR ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable]) - (SELECT [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable]))` if one for those queries returns more than one row, how is it going to do the subtract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: because following queries returns more than one row:

```
(
(SELECT [EMR ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable]) 
- 
(SELECT [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable])
) AS [LastWeekPendingProcessing]
```

and this happens because `[database].[dbo].[originaltable]` has two or more rows.

Solutions:

**[ 1 ]** Use a predicate to filter rows:

```
(SELECT [EMR ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable] WHERE <predicate>)
```

**[ 2 ]** Use an aggregate function:

```
(SELECT SUM/COUNT/...([EMR ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable])
```

Note: you could use

```
(SELECT [EMR ORDERS] - [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS] FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable] WHERE ...)
```

or

```
(SELECT SUM/...([EMR ORDERS] - [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS]) FROM [database].[dbo].[originaltable] WHERE ...)
```

Comment: According to my query, it should take the last week (from 5/11 to 5/17) and subtract the EMRORDERS from ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS

Comment: So my original WHERE has to be also entered inside the sub query?

Comment: I added another select statement and it's working fine now :) Thanks.